# How to manage/store static and dynamic data for an IOS App

Tags: ios, json, swift, database, dataset

My question might sound basic but it is more logic related about how to manage and store data in an IOS app.
I am not sure if I have to store my data in json or database or firebase as some of my data is static and some dynamic.
Imagine I am making a cooking app. I have JSON files of all ingredients, and cooking equipments (these are statics). This information will never change so they are in JSON. But I want users to use the library of ingredients and equipments to create recipes and I want to know what each user did with this information.
example:

```
{
  "User": 124213,
  "recipesList": [
    "recipe1",
    "recipe2"
  ],
  "date": "SomeDate"
}
```

Also each recipe would have a similar dependencies for example directions, ingredients, tools, and it will be referred to my static JSON files, such as `ingredients: [3, 1, 5, 3, ...]`

So my question is how I should set up my dataset. Do I need to have everything in a database such as firebase? But in that case why would user download static ingredients list each time when it never changes? Some part of the data is basic and never changes and some data which is about the user interactions and should get updated regularly.
Hope this is clear enough and this is more about the logic in managing and storing data.
Also what database is common to use for IOS apps?

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to map the JSON string into an object and then use the object to manipulate data, and in the moment that you have to send to the server the recipe or some change you can trasforma back the object into a JSON. If you use an object, the software will be simpler and cleaner.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, can you please provide a link to a tutorial for this purpose.

Comment: This is a fantastic Pod that I use to Map my object, is very easy to use and you can customise how data will be mapped https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/ObjectMapper